# XNA inneractive integration

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I'm trying to integrate the "inneractive SDK" in an XNA game for WP7.
It should be simple:

```
InneractiveAd.DisplayAd("MY_APP_ID", InneractiveAd.IaAdType.IaAdType_Banner, ??? , 120);
```

but i don't know what to put in the "rootGrid" field of type: System.Windows.Control.Grid

someone can help me?

Comment: You need to be more clear, and you should go back and accept answers to previous questions.

Comment: I'm trying to integrate "inneractive" in my project, i'm reading this simple guide: https://inneractive.jira.com/wiki/display/DevWiki/Windows+Phone+SDK+guidelines
The only required command is InneractiveAd.DisplayAd("MY_APP_ID", InneractiveAd.IaAdType.IaAdType_Banner, BannerAdGrid, 120); but i'm new in XNA and i don't understand what to put in the third parameter.

Comment: It really is "inneractive", not "interactive", right? (I almost "corrected" your spelling.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Windows.Control.Grid is a Silverlight control, and the ad service you are trying to use is meant for Silverlight Windows Phone apps, not XNA. You can either

- Create a Silverlight/XNA project, move your current XNA game into a frame of that project, and place the Ad in another frame; or
- Use a more universal Ad control such as [this one](http://wp7adrotator.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

My name is Nirit and I'm a support manager at inneractive.

Our WP7 SDK currently supports Silverlight, the XNA version is not ready yet, but it's indeed on our roadmap.

On Mango, XNA can be combined with Silverlight so in this case, you can use our SDK.
For further information regarding combining XNA and Silverlight projects please check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202938%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

In case Silverlight is not an option for you, please try our Server API (M2M protocol).

Our Server API can be found [here](https://inneractive.jira.com/wiki/display/DevWiki/Server+API+integration).

If you have any further questions, suggestions or comments, please feel free to contact me via the "Contact Support" link on your Dashboard.